# New kernel doesn't load after rpi-update

Tags: kernel, rpi-update

I'm a noob and want to update the kernel of my raspberry pi 2. I used the rpi-update utility but after I reboot I still see the old kernel under uname -r

```
ls /lib/modules/
4.1.17+  4.1.17-v7+  4.1.19-v7  4.4.38+  4.4.38-v7+
```

The files are there, but the output of uname -r is:

```
uname -r
4.1.19-v7
```

Answer (score 1):

> "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911

What you **SHOULD** have done was `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`.

You could try this and see what happens.

Comment: How do I roll back the `rpi-update` changes to the latest stable firmware without reinstalling Raspbian?